# Throwing exception when searching for "(double quotes) using predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I am trying to search for the charecter " using predicate but it is throwing exception due to the format may I know the solution to overcome this:

```
NSString *predicateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ like[c] \"'*%@*'\" AND %@ = \"%@\"", @"name", query, @"entitlementAccess", @"C"];

NSArray *groups =  [CoreDataManager managedObjectsForEntity:[DBGroup class]  withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat] limit:limit];
```

The exception is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "name like[c] "'*a"*'" AND entitlementAccess = "C""'
```

Comment: Thanks codester for fixing the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Beginners mistake: You think that stringWithFormat and predicateWithFormat do the same thing. They don't. predicateWithFormat has all the cleverness built in to make predicates work. stringWithFormat doesn't.

Comment: That doesn't really tell you have to fix the problem.

Comment: please suggest me a solution to fix this.